# Is it possible to plot multiple histogram the same way like tensorboard does in a notebook

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

Given some data frame we can easily plot the histogram for each column in a notebook like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.hist()
```

But instead of having one plot per column is it possible to plot it in one plot the same way tensorboard does it?

[image]

Is a [3D histogram](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/hist3d.html) the best we can do? Maybe using something different then matplotlib?